# Logging DB, should Dev, Test and Production all write to the same Log DB?

Tags: mysql, database, logging, nlog

I have done some search on internet, and I have learnt that it is a good practice to separate the logging DB from the main project DB...

If we have a dedicated logging DB, would it make sense to use the same logging DB for Dev, Test and Prod environments? or each environment requires its own logging DB?

The main reason that I though about using the same server, is the cost of having extra DBs... My aplication is in ASP.Net MVC, my Db is MySQL and I am using Nlog for logging.

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about? And what exactly do you mean with "logging DB"? Logging of error message (or other information from the application) is typically done into text files not databases.

Comment: Thanks, I am using MySQL. I am using NLog to write error messages to a separate DB, from my main project DB... I have configured NLog to write to DB, as I thought it would be easier to search than a text file...

Comment: If you are asking whether you should mix production, dev and testing, the answer is No. (Regardless of what part of the project you are thinking about mixing, such as a database)

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.